# How can this code be written shorter/clearer?

Tags: vb.net, code-readability, code-structure, code-standards

```
newRow("OrderReference") = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("*1003") + 5, line.IndexOf("*", line.IndexOf("*1003") + 5) - line.IndexOf("*1003") - 5)
```

There you have it. Very long and ugly. I was thinking about this:

```
Dim indexPlus = line.IndexOf("*1003") + 5
Dim indexMinus = line.IndexOf("*1003") - 5
newRow("OrderReference") = line.Substring(indexPlus, line.IndexOf("*", indexPlus) - indexMinus)
```

But that introduces new and meaningless vars. Unsatisfying.

Maybe RegEx is the savior here?

Unfortunately I mustn't change the input data `:-(`

The input data consist of the BWA-format (popular with books). Here you can see the part in question:
[image]

All codes in this example set are required. Only corresponding values change.

Comment: Shorter often means less clear

Comment: What happens if the line you're parsing look like, 1*234955555553829*10034902948.  What exactly are you expecting as a result?

Comment: I updated the question with more details. I guess some RegEx is the key here. The parsing line has always the format like stated in the enhanced details. So an odd behaviour won't happen. I expect the result to be "A.Müller-Schulz" in this case.

Comment: Is the data you're working with constant?  Meaning will what you're looking for always start with *1003?

Comment: Yes, data is constant. Always starts with *1003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your data is always constant, and what you're looking for always begins with "*1003", you don't need to use Regex (Even though you could).  Just use what you're already using but with some corrections.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "L10113540   VD44444     VD2002100234949     000116161       04201261\r\n";
        input += "  KN00010000000129000LPEUR003000001*1003A.Muller-Schulz*1017Bastei\r\n";
        input += "Lubbe.61204 Laund.Meine Schuld*1019KL*102990300*1030NO*1032EUR*1131KT";

        int start = input.IndexOf("*1003");
        int end = input.IndexOf("*", start + 1);
        string result = input.Substring(start + 5, end - start - 5);

        Console.WriteLine(result);

        // Your code
        start = input.IndexOf("*1003") + 5;
        end = input.IndexOf("*1003") - 5;
        result = input.Substring(start, input.IndexOf("*", start) - end);

        Console.WriteLine(result);

    }
}
```

### Result

```
A.Muller-Schulz
A.Muller-Schulz*1017Baste
```

You can see that what you posted in your question, doesn't give the results you want.  All you're really looking for is just the next asterisk after the first "*1003".  You can see the difference between your code and what I've given.

[.NET Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w3QQm3)

Comment: Thanks for this substantial insight. I mark this as correct answer as it seems there is not shorter way to do this. Shorter (RegEx) would be definitely less clear.

Answer (score 2):

I don't even think your second code works. It seems more like this.

```
Dim index = line.IndexOf("*1003") + 5
newRow("OrderReference") = line.Substring(index, line.IndexOf("*", indexPlus) - index)
```

10 - 5 - 2 isn't the same as 10 - (5 - 2) but instead it's the same as 10 - (5 + 2).

Next time, check out the codereview stack exchange.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks for checking. +1 for the codereview hint, didn't know that `:)`